# WxPython differences between Windows and Linux

Tags: python, windows, linux, user-interface, wxpython

The tutorials I've found on WxPython all use examples from Linux, but there seem to be differences in some details.

For example, in Windows a Panel behind the widgets is mandatory to show the background properly. Additionally, some examples that look fine in the tutorials don't work in my computer.

So, do you know what important differences are there, or maybe a good tutorial that is focused on Windows?

**EDIT:**  I just remembered this: Does anybody know why when subclassing wx.App an OnInit() method is required, rather than the more logical `__init__`()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed odd peculiarities in a small GUI I wrote a while back, but it's been a long time since I tried to the specifics are a rather distant memory. Do you have some specific examples which fail? Maybe we can improve them and fix the bugs?

Have you tried [the official wxPython tutorials](http://www.wxpython.org/tut-part1.php)? ...or were you after something more specific?

**r.e. your edit** - You should use `OnInit()` because you're subclassing [wx.App](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxapp.html#wxapponinit) (i.e. it's a requirement for wxWidgets rather than Python) and the wxPython implementation is wherever possible, just a wrapper for wxWidgets.

**[Edit]** Zetcode has [a fairly lengthy tutorial on wxPython](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/). I've not looked through it all myself, but it might be of some help?

The [`wxWidgets::wxApp::OnInit()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxapp.html#wxapponinit) documentation is fairly clear:

> This must be provided by the application, and will usually create the application's main window, optionally calling wxApp::SetTopWindow. You may use OnExit to clean up anything initialized here, provided that the function returns true.

If wxWidgets didn't provide a common interface then you'd have to do different things in C++ (using a constructor) compared to Python's `__init__(self,...)`. Using a language-independent on-initialisation allows wxWidgets ports to other languages look more alike which should be a good thing right? :-)

Comment: I understand that, but since every object oriented language has constructors, why require an OnInit()?

Comment: BTW, that tutorial is very short.

Comment: That's one of the tutorials I was talking about, but thanks anyway. It's still useful.

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT:**  I just remembered this: Does anybody know why when subclassing wx.App an OnInit() method is required, rather than the more logical `__init__()`?

I use `OnInit()` for symmetry: there's also an `OnExit()` method.

Edit: I may be wrong, but I don't think using `OnInit()` is required.

Answer (score 0):

I find a number of small differences, but don't remember all of them.  Here are two:

1) The layout can be slightly different, for example, causing things to not completely fit in the window in one OS when the do in the other.  I haven't investigated the reasons for this, but it happens most often when I use positions rather than sizers to arrange things.

2) I have to explicitly call `Refresh` more in Windows.  For example, if you place one panel over another, you won't see it the top panel in Windows until you call Refresh.

I general, I write apps in Linux and run them in Windows, and things work similarly enough so this is a reasonable approach, but it's rare for me when something runs perfectly straight out of the gate after an OS switch.

Comment: The documentation explicitly says that a Frame will only contain one widget so to add more you need to add a Panel.

As for layout, it seems that most "recent" windowing API's recommend that you use sizers to quasi-auto-layout your forms.  Once you get used to the idea, it's actually very convenient.  Means less work to support the wide range of screen sizes that users are likely to have.  No matter what size you optimise for, most users will use different font sizes and size their windows differently so your careful work ends up being wasted.